# purpose of first opperand in getelementptr

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I'm using LLVM version 3.4.2, and my question is regarding the getelementptr instruction. Say I have this c code, where I'm simply assigning the properties of a struct.

```
struct point {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

int main(void) {
  struct point my_point;

  my_point.x = 0;
  my_point.y = 0;
  my_point.z = 0;
}
```

If I where to compile it with `clang my_example.c -S -emit-llvm` this is the following llvm that is emitted.

```
%struct.point = type { float, float, float }

; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %my_point = alloca %struct.point, align 4
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.point* %my_point, i32 0, i32 0
  store float 0.000000e+00, float* %1, align 4
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.point* %my_point, i32 0, i32 1
  store float 0.000000e+00, float* %2, align 4
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.point* %my_point, i32 0, i32 2
  store float 0.000000e+00, float* %3, align 4
  ret i32 0
}
```

My question is what is the purpose of the first operrand on the lines calling `getelementptr`, such as

```
%1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.point* %my_point, i32 0, i32 0
%2 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.point* %my_point, i32 0, i32 1
%3 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.point* %my_point, i32 0, i32 2
                                                      ^^^^^
```

I'm guessing the second operand is the index of property inside the type `%struct.point`. But the first index is what's confusing to me. I figured it could be something similar to below, where the first opperand acted as an index in a pointer pointer.

```
int main(void) {
  struct point** my_point;

  my_point = alloca(sizeof(struct point**));
  my_point[0] = alloca(sizeof(struct point*));
  my_point[0]->x = 0;
  my_point[0]->y = 0;
  my_point[0]->z = 0;
}
```

But the emitted `LLVM` didn't match up. I figured it could be that the `getelementptr` instruction might accommodating for pointer pointers as well, clearly it wasn't.

From reading this it might became pretty obvious my knowledge of `LLVM` (and `C`) isn't the best, but it's enough for me to get by. So I'd appreciate it if your answer takes this into consideration so a amateur like myself can understand :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There' a [FAQ entry](http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#what-is-the-first-index-of-the-gep-instruction) about that.

`getelementptr` takes a pointer as first argument, which needs to be dereferenced. In terms of C code, think about these equivalent expressions:

```
my_point->x
```

is the same as

```
(*my_point).x
```

which in turn is the same as

```
my_point[0].x
```

That right there is the zero you're looking for.

As to your last example, `getelementptr` does address calculation, but no memory lookup, so it cannot handle iterated pointers. The correct input value would be a regular array like

```
struct point my_point[42];
```

The C expression

```
float *p = &my_point[7].y;
```

would then correspond to the LLVM IR

```
%1 = getelementptr %struct.point* %my_point, i32 7, i32 1
```

Comment: oh okay so that's kind of similar to what I was thinking about, except I had no idea `my_point[0]` was the same as `(*my_point)`.  I might actually look at that faq

Comment: @ABot: the C standard (C11 6.5.2.1 §2) defines `E1[E2]` as `(*((E1)+(E2)))` - nothing to do with LLVM, so I doubt it will be addressed anywhere in that FAQ

Comment: I figured that, but I haven't read the FAQ yet, and I figure there's a good chance there will be things in there that I have not yet picked up on.